# Balinese independent numerals partial reduplication

Tags: numbers, reduplication

[The Balinese numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balinese_numerals#Basic_numerals) in *dependent* and *independent* forms are given as linked. I just need to verify the assumptions that I made about the (possibly reduplicated) derived, independent form.

1) if the first syllable has a **CV** form, change it to *CV1CV2* where if V2 is **a** or **u** V1 is **a** otherwise if V2 is **e** or **i** V1 is **e**.

2) if the first syllable starts with an optional **a**, the **a** turns into a permanent vowel. (it sticks)

Note: thanks for the edit @user6726

Comment: V1 is never i. Let's assume you meant "e" not "i". Being a fan of facts over wiki, I recommend A. Clynes ANU dissertation on Balinese "Topics in the phonology and morphosyntax of Balinese based on the dialect of Singaraja, North Bali". Note that orthographic "e" is schwa. Your analysis matches the wiki claims, but there is evidence of vowel harmony that suggests that basically you have just *ə* which is subject to harmony. The details, however, are quite obscure.

Comment: isn't the 180degree orthographic e, schwa?

Comment: My perusal of Clynes suggests that the letter "e" in the wiki page is orthographic, and [ə] is spelled "e", distinct from "é".